# Find an xml element with some specific text using xpath or find in python using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to find all `book` elements with value `abc` i.e. `name` tag value. I used xpath:

`val= xml1.xpath('//bookstore/book/name[text()="abc"]')`

But it is returning None.

```
<bookstore>
 <book>
   <name>abc</name>
   <price>30</price>
 </book>
 <book>
   <name>Learning XML</name>
   <price>56</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: The XPath posted should work as far as I can see.. Maybe the problem is that your actual XML has default namespace, no?

Comment: The XPath in the question selects `name` elements. My interpretation is that the OP wants `book` elements that have a `name` child with a specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from lxml import etree

# Create an ElementTree instance 
tree = etree.parse("bookstore.xml")  

# Get all 'book' elements that have a 'name' child with a string value of 'abc'
books = tree.xpath('book[name="abc"]')

# Print name and price of those books
for book in books:
    print book.find("name").text, book.find("price").text
```

Output when using the XML in the question:

```
abc 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Added Id attribute to book tag.

`root.xpath("//bookstore/book/name[text()='abc']` it will give list of all `name` element which `text` is `abc` not parent element.

check following:

```
>>> data = """<bookstore>
...  <book id="1">
...    <name>abc</name>
...    <price>30</price>
...  </book>
...  <book id="2">
...    <name>Learning XML</name>
...    <price>56</price>
...  </book>
... </bookstore> """
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
>>> root.xpath("//bookstore/book")
[<Element book at 0xb726d144>, <Element book at 0xb726d2d4>]
>>> root.xpath("//bookstore/book/name[text()='abc']")
[<Element name at 0xb726d9b4>]
>>> root.xpath("//bookstore/book/name[text()='abc']/parent::*")
[<Element book at 0xb726d7d4>]
>>> root.xpath("//bookstore/book/name[text()='abc']/parent::*")[0].attrib
{'id': '1'}
```

---

Python beginner:

1. Create Parsing Object from that data.
2. Define parent list variable.
3. Iterate on `name` tags.
4. Check `text` of `name` tag is equal to `abc`.
5. if yes, then get parent of `name` tag and append to list variable.
6. Display result:

code:

```
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
>>> abc_parent = []
>>> for i in root.getiterator("name"):
...    if i.text=="abc":
...        abc_parent.append(i.getparent())
... 
>>> print abc_parent
[<Element book at 0xb726d2d4>]
>>> abc_parent[0].attrib
{'id': '1'}
```